# Error while creating extension in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pljava

I am using https://tada.github.io/pljava/install/install.html link to create pljava extension in postgresql.
Build is ok and there is no unsuccessful operation. However when i tried to create extension using the statement below:

```
create extension pljava;
```

It is giving me the error:

> ERROR:  java.text.ParseException: Excpected keyword 'SQLActions'

Internet gave me no result about this error. Any help is appreciated to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely unexpected. To begin to look for the cause, could you please run

```
pg_config --version --sharedir
```

and then also post the contents of

```
$SHAREDIR/extension/pljava.control
```

where `$SHAREDIR` is as reported by the `pg_config` command?

Have you ever had an earlier PL/Java version in use with this database?

Does `postgresql.conf` contain any settings of `pljava.*` or of `dynamic_library_path`?

Also, what's your operating system and version?

If you have a github account, you could open this as a PL/Java issue there.

Comment: Hi, I solve my problem by reinstalling my postgresql installation. That means it was not about pljava.

Comment: I'm glad that solved your problem! For anyone else reading this with a similar issue, please still feel free to report the details; there may be a solution that is simpler than reinstalling PostgreSQL.